# Passé composé ou imparfait dans le cas du verbe « savoir »

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé, imparfait

Imaginez quelques personnes qui ont découvert hier un magasin à côté de leur maison qui existe depuis longtemps.

Est-ce qu'il faut exprimer cette pensée avec imparfait (ils ne savaient pas assez longtemps)

> *Ils ne savaient pas jusqu'à hier* qu'il y avait un magasin à côte.

Ou c'est passé composé (l'action est terminée)

> *Ils n'ont pas su jusqu'à hier* qu'il y avait un magasin à côte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En utilisant le passé composé, on parle d'un évènement court, ici l'évènement qui leur a permis de le savoir (on est donc étonné qu'ils ne l'aient su qu'hier).

En utilisant l'imparfait, on parle d'un évènement sur la durée, donc toute la période où ils ont ignoré l'information (on est donc étonné qu'ils l'aient ignoré si longtemps).

La nuance est donc subtile. Il est possible d'utiliser les deux et vous serez compris sans problème. Le contexte autour de cette phrase permettra aussi de lever le doute sur ce qui vous étonne vraiment.